# Nifi stuck at "Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 41"

Tags: java, linux, docker, apache-nifi, alpine-linux

I have created a docker image for Nifi 1.14.0 with Alpine OS and jdk-8. I have been able to successfully build it but when I execute "./nifi.sh run" command in docker to run Nifi but it gets stuck at "Launched Apache NiFi with Process ID 41" and doesn't move beyond this unless I do Ctrl+C which shutdowns Nifi. Upon checking the nifi-app.log, it is seen that nar files have been unpacked and no errors are shown. Nifi-bootstrap.log and nifi-user.log don't show any errors eithers. What could be the possible reason and solution for this such that Nifi launches properly?

Thanks in advance!!

My Dockerfile is:

```
#getting base image Alpine

FROM alpine

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre

ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

ENV NIFI_VERSION 1.14.0

ENV NIFI_HOME /opt/nifi

RUN apk --update add bash git wget ca-certificates sudo openssh rsync openjdk8 zip && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* && \
    rm -rf /opt  && \
    mkdir -p /opt

RUN wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/nifi/$NIFI_VERSION/nifi-$NIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz && \
    tar xzf nifi-$NIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz -C /opt/ && \
    ln -s /opt/nifi-$NIFI_VERSION $NIFI_HOME && \
    rm nifi-$NIFI_VERSION-bin.tar.gz

RUN apk update --no-cache && apk upgrade --no-cache && apk add --no-cache bash libstdc++ libc6-compat

VOLUME ["$NIFI_HOME/conf"]

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR $NIFI_HOME
```

Comment: NiFi is secure by default - have you tried exposing port 8443 and accesing via https?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work

Comment: Here's a functional Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/dockerfile perhaps start with this and work backwards?

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out and made a few edits. It seemed to work but then I got the error - "tlsException: The truststore properties are not valid" and likewise for keystore properties as well. How can I correct that?